# ErrorException Undefined variable: addon

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> vendor/mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository/src/CoreComponentRepository.php:19

This is the code here

```
public static function initializeCache() {

        Cache::rememberForever($addon->unique_identifier.'-purchased', function () {

            return 'yes';

        });

    }
```

Please help me this is happening when i try to login in to the admin panel. rest is working fine. I have Php 7.4 with ubuntu os in plesk.

Comment: The error is clear, $addon is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

Your `$addon` variable is never defined in this function, and that's what the error is referring to. There are two options:

1. Pass it in your function where you're calling it and accept that parameter:

```
public static function initializeCache($addon) { //Param here
        Cache::rememberForever($addon->unique_identifier.'-purchased', function () {
            return 'yes';
        });
    }
```

2. Define in the beggining of the function

```
    public static function initializeCache() {
        $addon = 'Whatever this value has to be'; //Maybe load from database or config
        Cache::rememberForever($addon->unique_identifier.'-purchased', function () {
            return 'yes';
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function initializeCache() {
   foreach(Addon::all() as $addon){
        if ($addon->purchase_code == null) {
            self::finalizeCache($addon);
        }

    Cache::rememberForever($addon->unique_identifier.'-purchased', 
        function () {

        return 'yes';

    });
```

}
}